# Como cambiar el [criterio] de busqueda en una llmada $http de angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo link de JSON donde tengo que hacer búsquedas:

```
http://www.liverpool.com.mx/tienda?s=xbox&d3106047a194921c01969dfdec083925=json
```

pero necesito cambiar el criterio de búsqueda, por ejemplo para buscar `xbox` u otra cosa seria cambiar esto:

```
www.liverpool.com.mx/tienda?s=[criterio]& d3106047a194921c01969dfdec083925=json
                              ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Este es el código que tengo:

```
angular.module("liverpoolapp",["ngStorage"])
.controller("primerControlador",function($scope,$http,$localStorage) {
    $scope.posts = [];
    $http.get("http://www.liverpool.com.mx/tienda?s=xbox&d3106047a194921c01969dfdec083925=json")
    .success(function(data){
         console.log(data);
         $scope.posts = data;
     })
    .error(function(err){

    });

    $scope.grabar = function(){
        $localStorage.busqueda = $scope.busqueda;
    }
});
```

Comment: amigo tienes el codigo de tu html para ver como haces la llamada? no logro hacer una consulta

Answer (score 1):

Debes cambiar el `string` de búsqueda

```
angular.module("liverpoolapp",["ngStorage"])
    .controller("primerControlador",function($scope,$http,$localStorage){
        $scope.posts = [];

        var palabra_a_buscar = "producto";
        var url_busqueda = "http://www.liverpool.com.mx/tienda?s=" + palabra_a_buscar + "&d3106047a194921c01969dfdec083925=json";

        $http.get(url_busqueda)
            .success(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $scope.posts = data;
        })
        .error(function(err){

        });

        $scope.grabar = function(){
        $localStorage.busqueda = $scope.busqueda;
    }
});
```